# C# xmlns can't list nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I can't figure it out how to read the data from my xml.

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ToolSheet xmlns="http://www.mywebpage.hu/ControlDesigner" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <Sites>
    <Site name="Name1" telexCode="N1" />
    <Site name="Name2" telexCode="N2" />
    <Site name="Name3" telexCode="N3" />
    <Site name="Name4" telexCode="N3" />
  </Sites>

</ToolSheet>
```

Here is my C# code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(_filePath);

List<string> ret = new List<string>();

XmlNodeList value = doc.SelectNodes("ToolSheet/Sites/Site");
foreach (XmlNode node in value)
{
  ret.Add(node.Attributes["name"].Value);
}
```

I have already tried to use:

```
nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("mysn", "http://www.mywebpage.hu/ControlDesigner");

//After this read from the xml
XmlNodeList value = doc.SelectNodes("mysn:ToolSheet/Sites/Site");
//And tried much more syntax
```

I can't list the 'Sites' from my xml. Can someone help me out?

Comment: `xmlns` without a suffix declares the default namespace. That means that *all* of the elements, `Toolsheet`, `Sites` and `Site` are in that namespace.

Comment: I see, but how i supposed to select the nodes? What kind of sintax shall I use?
`mysn:ToolSheet/mysn:Sites/mysn:Site` I tried this but neighter this works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> results = ParseXml(FILENAME);
        }
        static List<string> ParseXml(string filename)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            return doc.Descendants(ns + "Site").Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("name")).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, it wors fine for me, but this have different syntax, then the `XmlDocument` Class, so i have to figure it out how to use it

Comment: XDocument is the newer Net Library that is used instead of XmlDocument (older library).